# C# Class does not exist in current context : public void CreateButton_Click

Tags: c#

```
public partial class NCAccountMakeInterface : Form
{
    GenerateUserClass ElUser = new GenerateUserClass(); BoxInformation Box = new BoxInformation(); ADStuff UsertoGenerate = new ADStuff();

    public void CreateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ElUser.UserNameValid != false && ElUser.POSValid != false && ElUser.PhoneNumberValid != false)
        {
            UsertoGenerate.GenerateAccount(Eluser); //This comes up with "ElUser" does not exist in current context
        }
    }
```

I'm fairly new to programming,  I need to be able to pass the information I've stored in the ElUser class  to this other class's function.

The information is generated for Eluser in another button.

I am stumped. I don't know if adding another object reference to CreateButton_Click would actually work.

I have less than a week to do this and get C# to read info off of a .csv file.

Comment: Did you use same namespaces for both classes?

Comment: Apart from the typo error (lower case u instead of uppercase), I think you need to understand the concept of instances of a class. Here you have created an instance of the class GenerateUserClass and I bet that this instance has nothing in common with the instance used in the other button code. Could you add the code where you initialize the information that you want to use here?

Comment: Oh my god... Thank you so much guys, it was the typo.

Comment: I had declared it all under the same namespace. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UsertoGenerate.GenerateAccount(Eluser);
```

This has a lowercase "u" in user (Eluser), your variable name has an uppercase U (ElUser)